# efficiently generating unique positive and negative triplets from two lists (source list and label list)

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and I would like to generate all unique triplets from two lists. So, I have two lists like so:

```
source_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..] # size N
labels_list=[1,1,0,2,1,3,6..] # size N
```

and I would like triplets of form:

```
<anchor> <postive> <negative>
```

where, `<anchor>` can be any element in the `source_list`, `postive` means that this element should come from the same label as the anchor(so, 1,2 and 1,5 could be seen as postive pairs in the triplet) and `negative'`s mean that they should be from a different label (so, 1,3 and 1,4 would be considered a negative pair of the triplet). So, some examples of the correct triplet would be:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 4
1, 2, 6
```

From the outset it seems like a `N choose k` problem, but I am not sure how to approach this with minimal computational cost other than doing loops with each element in python.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "from the same label" or "from a different label" means?

Comment: same label means that both the anchor and positive should correspond the same number in `labels_list` (e.g. 1 and 2 from the source_list have corresponding labels of 1,1) - same label and different label means anchor and negative should correspond to different numbers in the labels_list.(e.g.  1,3 from anchor and negative have corresponding labels of 1 and 0 - different labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a faster way to do this, but we can work it out pretty well with `numpy` and `itertools`. To get started, for each unique label *k* we need to partition `source_list` into the entries that correspond to label *k* (the "positive" part) and those that don't (the "negative" part).

```py
>>> source_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] #... size N
>>> labels_list = [1,1,0,2,1,3,6,2] #... size N

>>> for key in set(labels_list): 
...     positive = [s for i,s in enumerate(source_list) if labels_list[i] == key] 
...     negative = [s for i,s in enumerate(source_list) if labels_list[i] != key] 
...     print(key, positive, negative) 
...                                                                                 
0 [3] [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
1 [1, 2, 5] [3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
2 [4, 8] [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
3 [6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
6 [7] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

We can speed this up a little with NumPy and masking, which essentially lets us avoid doing the list comprehension twice.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> source_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> labels_array = np.array([1,1,0,2,1,3,6,2])  

>>> for key in np.unique(labels_array): 
...     mask = (labels_array == key)
...     positive = source_array[mask]
...     negative = source_array[~mask]   # "not" mask
...     print(key, positive, negative) 
...
0 [3] [1 2 4 5 6 7 8]
1 [1 2 5] [3 4 6 7 8]
2 [4 8] [1 2 3 5 6 7]
3 [6] [1 2 3 4 5 7 8]
6 [7] [1 2 3 4 5 6 8]
```

Side note: If `<anchor>` and `<positive>` aren't allowed to represent the same entry in `sources_list`, then we need each positive group to have at least two members in it. That probably happens in your actual data, but we'll just skip cases with a single positive for this demo.

Now comes the `itertools`. We want all unique permutations of 2 entries from the positive list, with another entry from the negative list. Since the results must be unique, we can cut down on complexity slightly be removing duplicates from each positive and negative list.

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> import numpy as np

>>> source_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> labels_array = np.array([1,1,0,2,1,3,6,2])  

>>> for key in np.unique(labels_array): 
...     mask = (labels_array == key)
...     positive = np.unique(source_array[mask])  # No duplicates
...     if len(positive) < 2:                     # Skip singleton positives
...         continue
...     negative = np.unique(source_array[~mask]) # No duplicates
...     print(key, positive, negative) 
...     for ((a,b),c) in itertools.product(itertools.permutations(positive, 2),
...                                        negative):
...         print(a,b,c)
...     print()
```

Output:

```
1 [1 2 5] [3 4 6 7 8]
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 6
1 2 7
1 2 8
1 5 3
1 5 4
1 5 6
1 5 7
1 5 8
2 1 3
2 1 4
2 1 6
2 1 7
2 1 8
2 5 3
2 5 4
2 5 6
2 5 7
2 5 8
5 1 3
5 1 4
5 1 6
5 1 7
5 1 8
5 2 3
5 2 4
5 2 6
5 2 7
5 2 8

2 [4 8] [1 2 3 5 6 7]
4 8 1
4 8 2
4 8 3
4 8 5
4 8 6
4 8 7
8 4 1
8 4 2
8 4 3
8 4 5
8 4 6
8 4 7
```

Comment: OMG! thank you so much for this detailed code - I wil read it and try to understand this. I was wondering if this was a binomial problem?

Comment: BTW: `Side note: If <anchor> and <positive> aren't allowed to represent the same entry in sources_list, then we..` I am not sure I understand what you are saying here. I presume you mean you cannot have <anchor> and <anchor> (where the second anchor represents the +ve) - then you are correct.