# List Problem in Python that I couldn't figure out

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have 10 different lists that have numbers from 0 to 10. Each of these 10 lists are 'person' and the numbers they contain is 'friend'. Numbers are the ID of them. So I have something like that:

```
person = 0   friend = 5
person = 1   friend = 2
person = 1   friend = 3
person = 1   friend = 4
person = 1   friend = 6
person = 1   friend = 8
person = 2   friend = 1
person = 2   friend = 4
person = 2   friend = 6
person = 2   friend = 7
person = 2   friend = 9
person = 3   friend = 1
person = 3   friend = 6
person = 3   friend = 8
person = 4   friend = 1
person = 4   friend = 2
person = 4   friend = 6
person = 4   friend = 7
person = 4   friend = 9
person = 5   friend = 0
person = 6   friend = 1
person = 6   friend = 2
person = 6   friend = 3
person = 6   friend = 4
person = 6   friend = 8
person = 7   friend = 2
person = 7   friend = 4
person = 7   friend = 9
person = 8   friend = 1
person = 8   friend = 3
person = 8   friend = 6
person = 9   friend = 2
person = 9   friend = 4
person = 9   friend = 7
```

Now I want to find the friends's friends of a person. I mean I want an output like that.

Person 0 is related with 5

Person 1 is related with 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 and also friends of these friends. so the output must be like that:

Person 1 is related with 2(4, 6, 7, 9), 3(6, 8), 4(2, 6, 7, 9), 6(2, 3, 4, 8), 8(3, 6). and also friends' friends' friends like:

Person 1 is related with 2(4(2,6,7,9), 6(1,3,4,8).........

Then I will remove the duplicate numbers from the list so I will have something like that:

Person 1 is related with, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9. Because person 1 has a relationship with all of them even It is indirectly. I am not sure if I was able to explain myself or not but you can ask me the point that is not clear. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for recursion.

Comment: Not the best title to have of the question.

Comment: @MayankPorwal could you please recommend me a better title

Comment: Can you share some sample data? I mean, the lists that you are dealing with. Bunch of assignments is not that helpful.

Comment: A better title would be 'Transitive closure in python'. That's what you're looking for. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure

Comment: Your "a is friend of b" relationship could be modeled with an *undirected graph* and then the set of all direct and indirect friends of a person would be the *connected component* of that person in the graph.

Comment: @BurningKarl it seems like this is a perfect solution to my problem. I used https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/ to implement it, and it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your list of friends for each person is stored like this:

```py
friends = {
    0: [5],
    1: [2, 3, 4, 6, 8],
    # and so on as in your question
    9: [2, 4, 7]
}
```

Then you could use a variant of the [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm to find the connected component of a person in this directed graph.

```py
def related_persons(person):
    visited = {person}
    to_be_investigated = {person}
    while to_be_investigated:
        current_person = to_be_investigated.pop()
        for friend in friends[current_person]:
            if friend not in visited:
                visited.add(friend)
                to_be_investigated.add(friend)
    return visited
```

This code is a little shorter and easier than [the code you linked to](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/).

**EDIT:** For a really good python graph library, take a look at NetworkX. It also has [the functionality you want](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.node_connected_component.html). I would not recommend to use it if you only need this one function, but it might be useful for a deeper analysis of your friendship graph.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what you're trying to do is like a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on a network of people. To better represent this network, you might try making a dictionary mapping `person -> set_of_friends`.

Let's start by putting your data into two lists, `persons` and `friends`:

```py
>>> persons = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]
>>> friends = [5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 6, 8, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 7]
```

Now let's construct the mapping from each person to their friends.

```py
>>> friend_dict = {key:{v for i,v in enumerate(friends) if persons[i] == key} for key in set(persons)}
>>> friend_dict
{0: {5},
 1: {2, 3, 4, 6, 8},
 2: {1, 4, 6, 7, 9},
 3: {1, 6, 8},
 4: {1, 2, 6, 7, 9},
 5: {0},
 6: {1, 2, 3, 4, 8},
 7: {2, 4, 9},
 8: {1, 3, 6},
 9: {2, 4, 7}}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923394/efficiently-generating-unique-positive-and-negative-triplets-from-two-lists-sou) (shameless plug) for a little tip on how to potentially speed this up with NumPy. Or, if you use `pandas`, you could get this info with a `groupby()`. Anyway, now we want to step through the dictionary twice (once to get to your friends, and once to get to *their* friends).

```py
>>> for person in friend_dict: 
...     friends_of_friends = set()
...     for friend in friend_dict[person]:                 # For each of my friends,
...         friends_of_friends.update(friend_dict[friend]) # look up their friends.
...     print(person, friends_of_friends)
...
0 {0}
1 {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}
2 {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}
3 {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8}
4 {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}
5 {5}
6 {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}
7 {1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9}
8 {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8}
9 {1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9}
```

Now you know everyone's friends (`friend_dict`), and you've just found the friends of everyone's friends.

Notice that 0 and 5 are connected to each other but no one else. It also looks like everyone else is connected eventually to someone else. Do you see now where recursion might come in handy? You want to keep stepping repeatedly through the dictionary until each of the sets of people that someone is connected to starts changing. Let's put it all together.

```py
>>> def step_through(friend_dict): 
...     new_friend_dict = friend_dict.copy() 
...     for person in friend_dict: 
...         for friend in friend_dict[person].copy():  
...             new_friend_dict[person].update(friend_dict[friend])  
...     if new_friend_dict != friend_dict: 
...         return step_through(friend_dict) 
...     else: 
...         return new_friend_dict 
...
>>> step_through(friend_dict)
{0: {0, 5},
 1: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 2: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 3: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 4: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 5: {0, 5},
 6: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 7: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 8: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 9: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
```

Again though, what you really want is a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) so that you don't keep crawling through the same pathways (see @BurningKarl's answer). You can also improve on this by keeping track of the pathways from each traversal (1 is a friend with 9 because it's friends with x who is friends with x who is...).

Finally, as @BurningKarl mentioned, it's pretty easy to do this whole process with `networkx` (you may have to `pip install networkx`).

```py
>>> import networkx as nx

>>> persons = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]
>>> friends = [5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 6, 8, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 7]
>>> friend_dict = {key:{v for i,v in enumerate(friends) if persons[i] == key} for key in set(persons)}

>>> graph = nx.Graph(friend_dict)
>>> list(nx.connected_components(graph))
[{0, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}]
```

Comment: Great answer, but I think you missed the point that the question also asked for "friends' friends' friends" and so on. So friends on any level of "relatedness" not just the first.

Comment: Updated the answer with the next step, a recursive solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Karl and SMcQ solutions are fine. I solved my problem with this one. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/ . Also tried other methods and all of them are working fine.